# How can I prevent duplicate methods for combobox selection change events?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, combobox

I'm working on my first C# project that isn't from a tutorial & it's getting...large.

It works, but I'm having to copy & past multiple methods that do the same thing for different selections. I have 8 different comboboxes with a corresponding textbox. Currently, all I've been able to get working is creating a separate method for each combobox.

This is an example of one of my methods. Whenever I select a new item from the combobox, I update a textbox with the appropriate serial #.

```
private void StationComboBox_1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost; username=PC;password=pw;"; 
    string query = "SELECT * from db.units where station_Units='"+ stationComboBox_1.SelectedItem +"';";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string serial = myReader.GetString("serial_Units");
            serial_1.Text = serial;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As it stands now, I'd have to make 7 more copies of that method, just changing the combobox name. I'm positive that's not the right way to do this.

I'd like to shrink my code significantly, but I'm really not sure how. I tried making a new class to refer to, but I'm totally lost. From what I can tell, I can't use another Class, since the UI elements would be on a different thread.

Comment: Parameterize. Write a method that does all that stuff, but has a parameter for the combobox: `public void UnitComboSelectionChanged(Combobox cb, TextBox tb) {...}`. In the body of that method, replace `stationComboBox_1` with `cb`, replace `serial_1` with `tb`. Call it from each event handler: `UnitComboSelectionChanged(stationComboBox_1, serial_1);`, in this case.

Comment: You are actually mixing data access with UI, which isn't recommended. Try to get informations about MVVM architecture, to separate the intentions.

Comment: You would typically have this code as a single function that accepts the value of the `ComboBox` as a parameter.  You would then have a single event handler for all of the `ComboBox`s that called the function with their `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method accepting the changing parts (ComboBox and Text) as parameters.

```
private void StationComboBox_1_SelectionChanged(object sender,
    System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTextFromSelection(stationComboBox_1, serial_1);
}

private void UpdateTextFromSelection(ComboBox comboBox, TextBox serialTextBox)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost; username=PC;password=pw;";
    string query = "SELECT serial_Units from db.units where station_Units=@unit;";
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(constring)) {
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", comboBox.SelectedItem);

        try {
            conn.Open();
            serialTextBox.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are retrieving a single value for the textbox, you can use `ExecuteScalar` method instread of creating a reader. `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row, therefore specify the `serial_Units` column in the select list instead of just `*`.

Note that I use a [parametrized query](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/parameters.html) in my example. It's usually easier to use, as you don't have to escape single quotes in strings and do not have to care about formatting dates or numbers the right way. Do not enclose the parameter name in quotes in the SQL text. Also, it protects you against [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

I also enclosed the connection object in a `using`-statement which automatically closes and disposes the connection at the end of the block.

If the textbox is always the same, you don't need to pass it as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

I've got one issue that I'm I'm working on solving now. "combobox.SelectedItem" is giving me the error "Argument 2:cannot convert from 'object' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType'

Comment: I'll keep a running list of what I've tried:
-Changed "object" before "sender" to "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType". Still gives me the same error.

Comment: I don't have the `MySql` library installed, so I cannot check. But maybe the `cmd.Parameters.Add` requires an additional `MySqlDbType` parameter. Look at the documentation of the library. Intellisense also gives you parameter information.

Comment: I got it working by reverting back to using             string query = "SELECT serial_Units from db.units where station_Units='" + combobox.SelectedItem + "';"; & removing the parameter.add line. I'm still not sure what it didn't like about the parametric query, but after hours fighting it, I gave in.